# only want to insert one row into other table

Tags: php, mysql

How do I get this to only insert one row of data, with selected fields inserted into another table by using the reference ?

so far I can only get all of the fields transferred when using the statement in phpmyadmin

```
$Reference=$_GET['Reference'];

$sql="INSERT INTO Triage (Reference, Forename) 
SELECT Reference, Forename from `Instruction` WHERE Reference='$Reference'"
```

Comment: Put LIMIT 1 for the select query you used..

Comment: @avisheks would that only bring back the select row? the reference will be in the address bar... where would I put the limit 1?

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO Table2(LongIntColumn2, CurrencyColumn2)
SELECT LongIntColumn1, Avg(CurrencyColumn) as CurrencyColumn1 FROM Table1 GROUP BY LongIntColumn1;

INSERT INTO prod_detail(prod_name,prod_code) select Name,Zip as data from info_tb where Name="mittal";

Comment: this doesn't help me much? how can I relate this to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$Reference=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Reference']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Triage (Reference, Forename)  
SELECT Reference, Forename FROM `Instruction` 
WHERE Reference='$Reference' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: I have added this to my logic but it does not add anything into the table.... it echoed ...INSERT INTO Triage (Reference, Forename) SELECT Reference, Forename FROM `Instruction` WHERE Reference='88888' LIMIT 1

Comment: I have ran it though phpmyadmin but doesn't work, I think its because the reference isn't defined though

Comment: you said Reference is '88888'. the possibility is there might not be any records having Reference '88888'. Run the select first, removing the insert, if its returning any rows

Comment: the record/reference gets defined in the table before hand, so there will always be that reference '888888' is an example. I just want to move the data for that record from one table to another.